# Upgraded Mysql 5.6 to MariaBD 10.3 - error in log

Tags: mariadb

I upgraded Mysql 5.6 to MariaDB 10.3 and now I have this line in error log, when I restart server:
[ERROR] mysqld: Plugin 'innodb' already installed

Server is running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. MariaDB is working, but I would like to get rid of this message.

I searched in Google but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your config probably tries to load Innodb support as an optional external module where in your current MariaDB install Innodb is already built-in and enabled by default.

If you don't want to remove that option completely you can convert the urgency of that message from an `Error`  to a `Note` by using the option `IF NOT EXISTS`: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/install-plugin/

Comment: I checked confing and I don't load InnoDB plugin. Can be something with migration from MySQL 5.7. I just installed trough apt install mariadb.

Comment: So, I completly removed MySQL, all confing end data and reinstalled MariaDB. Not I don't see any error message anymore.